# Can't delete underlying VM for a node in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running a three node cluster on GCE. I want to drain one node and delete the underlying VM.

Documentation for kubectl `drain` command says:

`Once it returns (without giving an error), you can power down the node (or equivalently, if on a cloud platform, delete the virtual machine backing the node)`

I execute the following commands:

1. Get the nodes

   ```
   $ kl get nodes
   NAME                                      STATUS    AGE
   gke-jcluster-default-pool-9cc4e660-6q21   Ready     43m
   gke-jcluster-default-pool-9cc4e660-rx9p   Ready     6m
   gke-jcluster-default-pool-9cc4e660-xr4z   Ready     23h
   ```
2. Drain node `rx9p`.

   ```
   $ kl drain gke-jcluster-default-pool-9cc4e660-rx9p --force
   node "gke-jcluster-default-pool-9cc4e660-rx9p" cordoned
   WARNING: Deleting pods not managed by ReplicationController, ReplicaSet, Job, DaemonSet or StatefulSet: fluentd-cloud-logging-gke-jcluster-default-pool-9cc4e660-rx9p, kube-proxy-gke-jcluster-default-pool-9cc4e660-rx9p
   node "gke-jcluster-default-pool-9cc4e660-rx9p" drained
   ```
3. Delete gcloud VM.

   ```
    $ gcloud compute instances delete gke-jcluster-default-pool-9cc4e660-rx9p
   ```
4. List VMs.

   ```
    $ gcloud compute instances list
   ```

   In the result, I'm seeing the VM I deleted above - `rx9p`. If I do `kubectl get nodes`, I'm seeing the rx9p node too.

What's going on? Something is restarting the VM I'm deleting? Do I have to wait for some timeout between the commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right track with draining the node first.

The nodes (compute instances) are part of a [managed instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/#managed_instance_groups). If you delete just them with the `gcloud compute instances delete` command the managed instance group will recreate them.

To delete one properly use this command (after you have drained it!):

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed delete-instances \
  gke-jcluster-default-pool-9cc4e660-grp \
  --instances=gke-jcluster-default-pool-9cc4e660-rx9p \
  --zone=...
```

Comment: I have had some major problems with scaling of node within GKE. I just implemented a system where my "worker" nodes check if there is a new task in my AMQP queue. If not, delete node. I noticed, it deletes the node but the VM remains active. And I can't use "kubectl drain [node-name]" from within a pod. Any ideas?